# How to find a basis for this subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let D be the set containing all the 3x3 upper triangular matrices with real entries.

Let E be the subset of D such that the sum of the diagonal entries is 0. How would you find a basis for this set?

Below is an example of a basis for E.

[image]

Comment: find a set of matrices that span D and are linearly independent

Comment: We can find an isomorphism $f:D\to\mathbb{R}^6$ let's say $$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\0&a_{22}&a_{23}\\0&0&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}\mapsto (a_{11}\quad a_{22}\quad a_{33}\quad a_{12}\quad a_{23}\quad a_{13})$$
We can get a basis for $E$ by finding a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for 
$$\{(a_{11}\quad a_{22}\quad a_{33}\quad a_{12}\quad a_{23}\quad a_{13})\in \mathbb{R}^6 :a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33}=0\}$$
and then $f^{-1}({\mathcal{B}})$ is a basis for $E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space you're interested in is
$$T_0 = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\0&e&f\\0&0&g\end{pmatrix} \mid a + e + g = 0\right\}.$$

If you drop the extra condition of the trace, you get a $6$ dimensional vector space, which I will denote by $T$. As $T_0 = \ker(\text{tr}_{\mid T})$ and because $\text{tr}_{\mid T}$ is non zero linear form, $T_0$ has dimension $5$. Hence, you have to find $5$ matrices which are in $T_0$ and linearly independant, and you have a lot of choice !

How one can find the $5$ matrices you gave ? It is quite natural to consider the following decomposition of $T_0$ :
$$T_0 =  \left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&b&c\\0&0&f\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\}\oplus \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&e&0\\0&0&g\end{pmatrix} \mid a + e + g = 0\right\}.$$
Therefore, a basis of $T_0$ can be the union of bases of the two subspaces, which, I hope, answers your question.